# Add permanent checkmark to tableView-cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, checkmark

my viewController contains a tableView where the user can add cells via coreData.
I defined the cells:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Travel";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSManagedObject *travel = [self.travelling objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *countryLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        kategorieLabel.text = [travel valueForKey:@"country"];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(15.0f, 32.0f, 24.0f, 20.0f);
        [cell addSubview:button];

            if ([[travel valueForKey:@"tick"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }else{
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
        return cell; 
    }

- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    UITableViewCell *owningCell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];
    [owningCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForCell:owningCell];
    NSManagedObject *travel = [self.travelling objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [travel setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"tick"];
    }
```

When the user taps a button on the cell, the checkmark should appear. But when I reload or restart the app not all checkmarks are there. Maybe there is a better method to do this.

Comment: Do you store `einkauf` (whatever that is) state/data?

Comment: sorry...I've renamed it...it's `travel`

Comment: You need to save the changes with core data.

Comment: @Kevin I thought I did this with my las line of code

Comment: @user2650439 You are setting the data, but not saving it. I believe you need to call [`-[NSManagedObjectContext save:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:) on your context.

Comment: Why is there no "if (cell == nil) { cell alloc }" in your cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @bachonk because he's using [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW92)

Comment: @Kevin But when I only reload this viewController (embedded in a navigationController) it works well

Comment: Yes, changes stay in memory while the program is running, unless you actively discard them, but they don't get written to disk until you save.  So if you don't save, the next time you run the program it will only have the old data.

Comment: Ok...I understand...now everything works perfectly :)